# SOQL query on fields related by polymorphic lookups

Tags: soql, polymorphism

Here is the SOQL query I am trying to make:

```
List<Task> tasks = [
   SELECT Id,ActivityDate,Status,Subject
   FROM Task
   WHERE What.Type = 'nexus__Goal__c'
   AND (What.nexus__Quarterly_Sales_Plan__c = 'a0EU0000004wz6B')
   LIMIT 101
];
```

Where `nexus__Quarterly_Sales_Plan__c` is a valid custom field I created on the `nexus__Goal__c` object, which is a valid target of the Task object's Polymorphic 'What' field.

When I run this query, I get the following error:

```
No such column 'nexus__Quarterly_Sales_Plan__c' on entity 'Name'. If
you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Will I have to wait for SOQL Polymorphism in Winter 13 in order for this Query to work? Or is there any way to make this work by specifying What.Type as I tried to do?

Comment: I have removed my answer as it was based on SFSE messing with your formatting and wasn't correct :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After my first answer your caught my interest so I went and had a play. 
I've tested using The eclipse data schema and it works for our instance:

```
SELECT WhatId, ActivityDate 
FROM Task 
WHERE WhatId IN (
    SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Type = 'test'
)
```

I imagine this converting to:

```
SELECT Id,ActivityDate,Status,Subject 
FROM Task 
WHERE WhatId IN (
    SELECT Id FROM nexus__Goal__c WHERE nexus__Quarterly_Sales_Plan__c = 'a0EU0000004wz6B'
)
```

Comment: Jon, great suggestion! I will try this out and let you know how it goes for me.

Comment: Looking at my answer I realise that the `What.Type = 'nexus__Goal__c'` line is kind of redundant!

Comment: Yeah, that's okay :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Jon, I removed the What.Type clause from your answer as you are correct, it is redundant. Don't want anyone to be confused and think that it makes a difference if it's there.

Comment: Thanks @zachelrath (and also Saariko for being a ninja like mod and reviewing within 11 mins :P)